Android Studio Time PIcker Clock Color
pic1
(UPDATE) I want to make this a custom time picker ( as a separate layout) so it would be easier to modify.
I want to change the clock color into secondary but I can't get it right
<style name="TimePickerDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/secondary</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">@color/background</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
        <item name="android:numbersBackgroundColor">@color/background</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#4CAF50</item>
        <item name="android:amPmBackgroundColor">@color/secondary</item>
        <item name="android:color">@color/secondary</item>
        <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/background</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/circular_medium</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/circular_regular</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/light</item>
    </style>

I tried changing the color but still doesn't change the color. Also i want to change the background for the ":" and "AM/PM"
[enter image description here]
(https://i.sstatic.net/FGVOj.png)

taskTime.setOnTouchListener((view, motionEvent) -> {
            if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // Get Current Time
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                // Launch Time Picker Dialog
                timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.TimePickerDark, (view12, hourOfDay, minute) -> {
                    taskTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                    timePickerDialog.dismiss();
                }, mHour, mMinute, false);

                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
            return true;
        });


Better use MaterialTimePicker where you can customize whatever you want.
  final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Integer mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    Integer mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    Integer timeFormat = TimeFormat.CLOCK_24H; // (or TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H)
    
    MaterialTimePicker timePicker = new MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
            .setHour(mHour)
            .setMinute(mMinute)
            .setTimeFormat(timeFormat)
            .setTheme(R.style.TimePickerDialogStyle)
            .build();

    timePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            taskTime.setText(timePicker.getHour() + ":" + timePicker.getMinute());
        }
    });

    timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TimePicker");

Styles
 <style name="TimePickerDialogStyle" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TimePicker">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="materialClockStyle">@style/TimePicker.Clock</item>
    <item name="materialButtonOutlinedStyle">@style/TimePicker.Button</item>
    <item name="imageButtonStyle">@style/TimePicker.ImageButton</item>
</style>

<!--center clock in timepicker-->
<style name="TimePicker.Clock" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TimePicker.Clock">
    <item name="clockFaceBackgroundColor">@color/blue</item> <!--center clock background color-->
    <item name="clockHandColor">@color/blue</item> <!--selected time in center clock color-->
    <item name="clockNumberTextColor">@color/blue</item> <!-- color of numbers around the central clock-->
</style>

<!--AM/PM style-->
<style name="TimePicker.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TimePicker.Button">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">0dp</item>
</style>

<!--keyboard/clock icon style on bottom left in dialogue-->
<style name="TimePicker.ImageButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TimePicker.ImageButton">
    <item name="iconTint">@color/blue</item>
</style>

Additional Link that may help
MaterialDialog example and styles

The thing is that I've tried that but it is less performant, it messes up all my code and design, and it doesn't integrate in my code : https://pastebin.com/wMMxQcf4

I have modify a little bit, i just want to modify that gray color to be for example green color

@Mausica have you tried this https://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2019/09/android-timepicker-dialog-styling.html ? TimePicker dialogue style is added there to AppTheme and the color changes, otherwise no, that's why I said to use MaterialTimePicker.

This is the reason why I put the question here, I succeeded with the Date Picker, but then when I tried on Time Picker exactly the clock in the middle doesn't changes its colors, and it's annoying.
